# Has anyone integrated Exacttarget with the Chrome Push Api

Tags: marketing-cloud

Interested in leveraging browser push notifications through the chrome push API. Has anyone worked around this?
Use case would be to send a message to a visitor while browsing our site.

Answer (score 2):

That's a great question. There's a good video tutorial from Google Dev Summit [available here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uh0IASBexdM&list=PLNYkxOF6rcICcHeQY02XLvoGL34rZFWZn&index=5) which is a step-by-step guide how to implement. I found this a helpful introduction.

It would be good to see native browser push notifications in future versions of Marketing Cloud — there's a lot of opportunity to integrate this into customer journeys too; an Event could be fired when a visitor opens a cloud page which could cause them to enter an Interaction and receive a push notification. I'd like to build such a Custom Activity when I have some time to spare!